# Аналог get-caller-identity в Ya.Cloud

Tags: yandex-cloud

В aws cli есть команда [get-caller-identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) с её помощью можно узнать кто вызывает cli и проверить работает ли cli вообще. Есть ли какой-то похожий аналог для Ya.Cloud что бы можжно было сделать вызов без прав и убедится, что яндекс cli работает?

Answer (score 0):

Да, такой командой можно считать `yc iam create-token`. [Документация](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/cli/cli-ref/managed-services/iam/create-token)

Она обратится к серверам Identity and Access Management сервису Облака и обменяет долгоживущие credentials, указанные в конфиге (OAuth-токен или JWT-токен, подписанный приватным ключом сервисного аккаунта), на IAM-токен.

Время жизни IAM-токена не превышает 12 часов. Он может быть использован для авторизации почти во всех сервисах Облака.

Эта команда может быть **выполнена от любого субъекта и не требует дополнительных прав**. А вот сможете ли вы с этим токеном авторизоваться для выполнения каких либо действий в Облаке, будет зависеть от ролей назначенных субъекту, от имени которого выписан токен.